# Changing Compose Light/Dark XML theme without extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to programatically alter the light/dark theme from a user setting in Compose if the user decides to override their OS level setting and have the values read from the `colors` and `night/colors` files.

Jetpack compose by default extends `ComponentActivity` as extending `AppCompatActivity` would be extending `FragmentActivity` which is not needed when doing a Compose only app.

When I'm extending `ComponentActivity` the `AppCompatDelegate` methods to change light/dark mode no longer function because I'm not extending `AppCompatActivity`

E.g `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

If I instead extend `AppCompatActivity` it works as you would expect.

It seems silly to extend `AppCompatActivity` when I don't need to, but I can't find any other way to tell a compose app to use the correct xml values based off user input?

Am I missing something, or does this capability not exist yet, and I need to extend `AppCompatActivity`

Compose has the programmatic themes which I can change, but I want to use the XML color files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend `AppCompatActivity` if you want to use any API from AppCompat, including the light/dark mode theme changing using XML color files available via the `AppCompatDelegate` APIs.

Comment: Well I know that.  I'm asking if there's another way that doesn't use AppCompatDelegate because it's a waste to extend AppCompatActivity if I don't need to when using Compose

Comment: You do need it if you want to use XML color files. That's something you only get via AppCompat.

Comment: If thats truly the case, you should update your answer as such so I could mark it as answered.  It wouldn't be quite correct as is.

Comment: That's what I meant by 'the light/dark mode theme changing', but I've updated the answer to call out exactly what I meant by that.